# Can't install magento 1 - "The URL is not accessible. Unable to read response, or response is empty"

Tags: magento-1, installation

I try to install magento 1 on a local server.

I fail at the "Configuration" step.

[image]

The project is reachable under a VHOST which I have called **http://entwicklung.m1fresh/**

But if I press next, I get:

> "The URL is not accessible. Unable to read response, or response is
>   empty"

Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the option :
**Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step**
[image]
And continue with the steps.

Comment: Done . Glad it helped @Black